# Set apart functions

Tags: php

What is good way:
Keep all functions in one file or to set apart them? (like database.php, session.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach is split functionalities into classes; and then to put each class into one file.

If you have a lot of functions, I would do the same - split them into thematically separate files and include them only when needed.

If you work with classes, you can make use of PHP's [autoloader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) functionality that will automatically load any PHP files needed to instantiate a certain class.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using several distinct files -- generally, one per "*group of features*".

Advantages :

- smaller files : easier to deal with in your IDE
- several files : one developper can work on one feature, in one file, the other developper on another feature, in another file ; limits the risks of conflicts *(yes, even with SVN and equivalents)*
- you only need to include what's needed

*(And if you extend your question to classes : one class per file, structured in directories ; and using autoloading to include the files that are necessary)*